# Arcgis JSAPI, Error: <circle> attribute cx: Expected length, "NaN"

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm using Arcgis JSAPI 4.3 to develop an application. 
I'm trying to display some public events on map using a public API provided an events website.

I had XMLHttpRequest response as Json data that includes events latitude and longitude information of many events.

But I'm getting **this error** in console;
**MapView.js:379 Error:  attribute cx: Expected length, "NaN".**

****Error screenshot ****
[image]

**When I drag map, error count is increasing more and more.**

**And marker is always displaying at top left corner as seen below.**
[image]

```
var latitude = [];
var longitude = [];
eventIO.request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {

      listItems = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      data = listItems.recs;

      for (var j=0; j < data.length; j++) {
        latitude.push(data[j].venue.lat);
        longitude.push(data[j].venue.lng);
      }
}


  require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/PopupTemplate",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/Graphic",
    "esri/geometry/Point",
    "esri/geometry/Multipoint",
    "esri/geometry/Polyline",
    "esri/geometry/Polygon",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(
    Map, PopupTemplate, MapView,
    Graphic, Point, Multipoint, Polyline, Polygon,
    SimpleMarkerSymbol, FeatureLayer
  ) {   

    var map = new Map({
      basemap: "hybrid"
    });

    var view = new MapView({
      center: [30, 40],
      container: "viewDiv",
      map: map,
      zoom: 6
    });

    var myPoints = {"points": [[longitude, latitude]]};
    var multipoint = new Multipoint(myPoints);

    var markerSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol({
      color: [226, 119, 40],
      outline: {
        color: [255, 255, 255],
        width: 2
      }
    });

    var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
      geometry: multipoint,
      symbol: markerSymbol
    });

    view.then(function() {
      view.graphics.add(pointGraphic);
    });

  });
```

**Console log screenshot of "multipoint"**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The API documentation, [multipoints property "points"](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Multipoint.html#points), asks for an array of Number, and the console log show that your array of points, contains strings, ie: `"40.993603"`

Modify your for loop to convert latitude and longitude values, to float.

I even suspect you don't correctly form the array of points to build your multipoints. In this for-loop, you should push longitude and latitude in the same array.

```
var points = [];
for (var j=0; j < data.length; j++) {
  points.push([parseFloat(data[j].venue.lng, parseFloat(data[j].venue.lat)]);
}
```

Then : `var multipoint = new Multipoint({"points" : points})`

Answer (score 0):

I've converted strings to numbers in array and NaN values to fixed values.

I have changed my code such as below;

```
latitude.push(parseFloat(data[j].venue.lat) || 40 );
longitude.push(parseFloat(data[j].venue.lng) || 29 );
points.push([(parseFloat(data[j].venue.lat) || 40 ),(parseFloat(data[j].venue.lng) || 29 )]);
```

[image]

It fixed now. Thanks for your help again.

[image]